# How to avoid hovering in the active tab?

Tags: html, css

When I pass the pointer over a `tabs` that is already active, another `hover` border appears on it.

How can I prevent a `hover` from being performed in a `tabs` that is already active.

```css
ul.tabs-list {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #8563CF;
}
.tab-item {
    font-size: .875em;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
}
.tab-item span {
    padding: 1em;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.3em;
}
.tab-item span:hover{
    border-bottom: 3px solid #02cfc0;
}
.tab-active span {
    color: #8563CF;
}
.tab-active {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #02cfc0;
}
```

```html
<div class="horizontal-tab">
    <ul class="tabs-list">
        <li class="tab-item active-tab tab-active">
            <span data-target="#1">All item</span>
        </li>
        <li class="tab-item">
            <span data-target="#2">PHP</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tabs-container">
        <div id="1" class="tab-content tab-content-active" style="">
            <div class="tab-content" style="">
                A
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="2" class="tab-content" style="display: none;">
            <div class="tab-content" style="">
                B
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use not selector in for hover css i.e., `.tab-item :not(.active-tab) span:hover`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `:not(.tab-active)` to your existing rule like `.tab-item:not(.tab-active) span:hover{`

```css
ul.tabs-list {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #8563CF;
}
.tab-item {
    font-size: .875em;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
}
.tab-item span {
    padding: 1em;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.3em;
}
.tab-item:not(.tab-active) span:hover{
    border-bottom: 3px solid #02cfc0;
}
.tab-active span {
    color: #8563CF;
}
.tab-active {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #02cfc0;
}
```

```html
<div class="horizontal-tab">
    <ul class="tabs-list">
        <li class="tab-item active-tab tab-active">
            <span data-target="#1">All item</span>
        </li>
        <li class="tab-item">
            <span data-target="#2">PHP</span>
        </li>
                <li class="tab-item">
            <span data-target="#2">PHP</span>
        </li>
                <li class="tab-item">
            <span data-target="#2">PHP</span>
        </li>
                <li class="tab-item">
            <span data-target="#2">PHP</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tabs-container">
        <div id="1" class="tab-content tab-content-active" style="">
            <div class="tab-content" style="">
                A
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="2" class="tab-content" style="display: none;">
            <div class="tab-content" style="">
                B
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's going great.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:
`.tab-item span:hover{ border-bottom: 3px solid #02cfc0; }`

With this:
`.tab-item:not(.tab-active) span:hover{ border-bottom: 3px solid #02cfc0; }`